# Umbraco custom section validate required fields

Tags: angularjs, umbraco

I'm developing a custom section in Umbraco Backoffice and I having some troubles with required fields validation.

I want to prevent the click of the form button if any required field is unfilled, and then show the validation message for this field.

This is my form code

```
    <form name="evaluationForm" val-form-manager class="show-validation">
       <div class="ng-scope">
       <div class="umb-property ng-scope" data-element="property-questionTitle">
          <div class="control-group umb-control-group">
             <div class="umb-el-wrap">
                <label class="control-label ng-binding" for="questionTitle" title="questionTitle">
                Título <strong class="umb-control-required">*</strong>
                <small class="ng-binding">Añade un título a la pregunta.</small>
                </label>
                <div class="controls">
                   <div class="umb-property-editor ng-scope">
                      <div>
                         <div class="ng-scope">
                            <input name="questionTitle" type="text" class="umb-editor umb-textstring"
                       ng-model="vm.model.questionSelected.Title"
                       required />
                            <span class="help-inline" val-msg-for="questionTitle" val-toggle-msg="required">Required</span>
                         </div>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    <umb-button action="vm.functions.saveQuestion()"
          type="button"
          button-style="success"
          state="vm.buttonState"
          disabled="vm.buttonState === 'busy'"
          label="Guardar">
    </umb-button>
    </form>
```

Comment: A bit of a stab in the dark, but maybe set ng-required instead? And then button disabled state could also be determined by evaluationForm.$valid ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `disabled="vm.buttonState === 'busy'"` property from your `<umb-button>` into `disabled="evaluationForm.$invalid"`.

(where `evaluationForm` is the name of the form and `$invalid` is the state of the form)

You can also show 'only' the validation message by inserting `ng-show="evaluationForm.questionTitle.$dirty && evaluationForm.questionTitle.$invalid"` into your `<span class="help-inline" val-msg-for="questionTitle" val-toggle-msg="required">Required</span>`

(where `evaluationForm` is the name of the form and `questionTitle` is the name of the input control to check)